# Not Displaying error message in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Whenever i try to add project of same name it leads to IntegrityError at /admin instead there should be an Error message on Django admin that "This project already exists". Also i have two users. So same user cannot have project of same name and different users can have project of same name. Please let me know how to fix this.

```
class Project(models.Model):
 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "added_by"),)
```

Comment: Have you recently modified your model and forgotten to migrate it?

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, i have modified models and i have migrate them. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Getting an `IntegrityError` generally indicates that your model and your database are not in sync. Double check the unique constraints on your tables using the client software (such as pgAdmin for PostgreSQL).

Comment: I am using xammp with phpmyadmin.Should i give some validation error?

Comment: Check if you really have a composite unique constraint (`name`+`added_by`) using phpMyAdmin. I believe you still have a single column constraint on the `name` column.

Comment: Yes i have Project and added by id .